# Importing one picture multiple times in qualtrics

Tags: image-processing, qualtrics

I'm trying to make personalized surveys in Qualtrics. For each survey I need to upload 350 of the same image and another image 350 times in the questions in one survey, since I need to do this for 40 surveys this would mean I would have to upload 28000 pictures manually. Now I have been looking for a way to upload the images one time in Qualtrics so I can easily assign them to the question where the need to be displayed. I have been looking all over the web for a way to do this but no result yet. So any ideas, suggestions, previous experiences, tips would be greatly appreciated.

If I need to explain it further or need to make something clearer please let me know.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the answer possibilities are different for each question, so I can't just make one question and duplicate this a bunch of times.

Comment: Can you upload them elsewhere (like Amazon S3) and then just mass upload URLs for each into Qualtrics?

Comment: Is the only change bellow each picture just text of question choices? If so, what about using Loop and Merge with question choices in fields?
https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/block-options/loop-and-merge/